# Prove that $m^2 = n^2$ if and only if $m = n$ or $m = -n$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Prove that $m^2 = n^2$ if and only if $m = n$ or $m = -n$

---

I assume I need to setup my propositions like so:

$(m^2 = n^2) \iff ((m = n) \lor (m = -n))$

$((m^2 = n^2) \implies ((m = n) \lor (m = -n)) \land ((m = n) \lor (m = -n)) \implies (m^2 = n^2))$

My first problem is that I don't think I have setup my propositions right, and my second problem is that I am puzzled by how I could prove this?

Comment: For starters, you need to specify in what ring or field you are working.  This statement is not true for quaternions.  ($i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$ but $i\neq j$ and $i\neq -j$)

Comment: @JMoravitz what do you mean? I am new to logic based things. This is I believe under predicate logic.

Comment: Just think out what you want to say in symbolic form.

Comment: @Fogest I mean, the full statement of the problem should describe what $m$ and $n$ are.  For example "for all $m,n\in\mathbb{R}$ you have that $m^2=n^2 \Leftrightarrow m=n$ or $m=-n$."  We don't always work with $m,n\in\mathbb{R}$, the field of real numbers.  We might sometimes choose to work in other more abstract fields or rings, such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion and what is true in one ring might not necessarily be true in another.

Comment: @JMoravitz this is all the information I am given in the question. I don't have anything else. Based on previous questions I would assume the domain is restricted to integer values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're over the reals, one direction is easy: $m=n$ or $m=-n$ implies $m^2=n^2$, since $(-1)^2=1$. The other direction can be done multiple ways. You could write $m^2-n^2=(m-n)(m+n)=0$. Now show either $m+n=0$ or $m-n=0$.

Comment: The question doesn't say that I am using real numbers, or integers, so I guess I can state my own domain, which to make it easier I guess I'd go with integers. I am fairly new to proofs. Would you mind giving an example of how you'd prove that $m + n = 0$?

Comment: If the domain is an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain such as the integers, $\mathbb{Z}$, or any field such as the real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, then you have that if $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$ then $a\cdot b\neq 0$.  Equivalently by contrapositive, if $a\cdot b = 0$ then at least one of $a$ or $b$ equals zero.

Comment: @JMoravitz any reason why you switched to using $a$ and $b$? Is this because you are referencing a known proof? I am fairly new to this so words like `Integral domain` I have never even heard mentioned before.

Comment: I switched to using $a$ and $b$ because I am referencing a known *property*.  In your exact example, you can take $a=(m-n)$ and $b=(m+n)$.  You can take the property I mentioned as a definition since that is how an integral domain is defined.  In the case of a field, it follows directly from the axioms.  By definition in a field, if $x\neq 0$ then $\frac{1}{x}$ exists and $\frac{1}{x}\cdot x = 1$.  Also, $0x + 0x = (0+0)x = 0x$ so $0x = 0$.  Finally, to prove my statement, let $x\neq 0, y\neq 0$ but $xy=0$.  Then $1=\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{x}xy = \frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{x}0=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you!!!

Comment: Again, for the time being, you will likely only be working with the real numbers or the integers, maybe the rational numbers or complex numbers.  These properties will be true for them and can practically be taken as definitions, but there are other stranger number systems out there for which it might not be true, so it is important to know exactly in which number system you are working.

Comment: @Fogest e.g. in the integers mod $\,8\,$ we have $\,3^2\equiv 1^2,$ but $\,3\not\equiv \pm 1,\,$ and the quadratic polynomial $\, x^2-1\,$ has $\,4\,$ roots $\,x\equiv \pm1,\,\pm 3.\ $ The proof breaks down because $\,(3-1)(3+1) = 2\cdot 4\equiv 0,\,$ but $\,4,2\not\equiv 0\ \ $